# How do I fix the install error for my video driver?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia-geforce

This is the error message I keep getting when trying to install the nvidia driver, libnvidia-gl-390_390.87.Can somebody help me resolve this issue? Please be aware that I am ubuntu challenged.

```
(Reading database ... 210321 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-390'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-390:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-390:
 nvidia-driver-390 depends on libnvidia-gl-390 (= 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1); however:
  Package libnvidia-gl-390:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-390 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386:
 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 depends on libnvidia-gl-390; however:
  Package libnvidia-gl-390:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-driver-390
 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Please edit your question to include the command you used before the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The output says that `libnvidia-gl-390:i386` is not installed and it looks like `libnvidia-gl-390:i386` needs to be installed to fix the issue. Run the following commands and please post any errors:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall libnvidia-gl-390:i386
sudo apt -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If you get an error, please post the error.

Comment: Thanks mchid. I did get an error message. As follows....

Comment: sudo apt upgrade list
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-ifr1-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 but it is not installed
 nvidia-driver-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 (= 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: error message for reinstall libnvidia... sudo apt install --reinstall libnvidia-gl-390:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-file debtags libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libnih-dbus1
  libregexp-assemble-perl libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-390
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.

Comment: 2nd part of comment.... Need to get 0 B/14.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 73.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 210321 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-390'

Comment: last part of error message, sorry if I am doing this wrong with add comment....found 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-390:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

OK... I found that someone else was having the same problem I am on the ubuntu forums.

I tried this suggestion in terminal...

LC_MESSAGES=C dpkg-divert --list '*nvidia-340*' | sed -nre 's/^diversion of (.*) to .*/\1/p' | xargs -rd'\n' -n1 -- sudo dpkg-divert --remove
sudo apt --fix-broken install

After which I ran sudo apt --fix broken install

Then ran sudo apt upgrade

This worked for me. 
Thanks  for your help